# Why do I not get a good binary image with a grey background using the mahotas python module?

Tags: python, image-processing, mahotas

I got some problems with image with grey background with mahotas library:

Example:[image: input image]

This is the code:

```
import mahotas as mh
path ="./imagepath/a.jpg"
fork = mh.imread(path)  
bin = fork[:,:,0]
bfork = bin <230
```

After that i got that:
[image: output image]

What have i do for getting a black background and a white sign?
I tried in opencv module and was good, but i prefer mahotas.

```
import cv2
path ="./imagepath/a.jpg"
ow =  int ((oshape[0]/100 )*7 )
oh =  int ((oshape[0]/100 )*7 )
gray = cv2.imread(path,0)
element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(ow,oh)) 
graydilate = cv2.erode(gray, element) 
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(graydilate,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV) 
bin = thresh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing the same as in the opencv version. If you do, you'll get the wanted results:

```
fork = mh.imread(path)
bin = fork[:,:,0]
bin = mh.erode(bin)
bin = (bin < 127)
```

The erosion step was missing and the threshold was different.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(bin)
plt.gray()
```

[image: Binarized fork]

Comment: It works except with these images: http://i.imgur.com/eGTc2OP.jpg, http://i.imgur.com/LV7QUMX.jpg?  Have i to change again the parameters?

Comment: Using a hard coded threshold (127 in this case) is often not the best. I might also try running a median filter as a preprocessing step.

Comment: Can you determine if the background is white or gray, and so use a different binarization setting for each? 127 for grey background and 170 for white background.